# Cannot debug with Counterclockwise

Tags: clojure, eclipse-plugin, counterclockwise, ccw

I am running Clojure/Eclipse/Counterclockwise. When I insert a breakpoint in core.clj there is only one line in which the dot acquires a small tail. That is line 29. This is independent of what code is on line 29. When this dot with tail is present and I try Run/Debug/Debug Configuration/Debug then the dialog box times out with a message "Waiting for new REPL process ack timed out". Also, the focus moves to the tab for file clojure.core. Line 29 on that file is the one starting with "cons" below. It is the last line in the definition of cons. It is also the first line in clojure.core where ". clojure.lang.RT" appears (there are other similar lines below). On the debug window I see "Thread [main] (Suspended) and immediately below "core.clj line: 29". It looks like the problem is with .clojure.lang.RT. Can anyone help?

(If I insert a breakpoint in any other line I just get a dot and the REPL starts but the breakpoints are ignored.)

```
(def
 ^{:arglists '([x seq])
    :doc "Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is
    the rest."
   :added "1.0"
   :static true}

 cons (fn* ^:static cons [x seq] (. clojure.lang.RT (cons x seq))))
```

Comment: You should re-word this. Unclear.